# Angular Iframe is loaded correctly, but it is not working in CHROME

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have embedded an iframe in Angular like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-selector',
  template: `<iframe *ngIf="true" [src]="'https://stackoverflow.com/examplewebsite/login' | safeUrl" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>`,
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']
})

export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(...) {...}
  ngOnInit() {...}
```

Iframe is loaded properly, and working properly(I have to log in in it) in Firefox, but not logging in in Chrome
There are some errors in console HTML code 401

Comment: so 401 is unauthorized so probably means auth headers. Hard to guess what would cause it.

Comment: But, how can happen that in Firefox is working properly without any errors in authorization from the same website? Could you suggest me something to try different?

Comment: Disable your extensions and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: But, this has to work for all users of the website.